# Chrome Speech Recognition API stopped working in one browser, but works in Canary (MacOS)

Tags: google-chrome, audio, microphone, speech-recognition

I've been using the Speech Recognition API for a few years now (nothing too complex), but after not using it for about a year it is no longer working in my main Chrome browser: Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit).

I am testing in three different sites– two are my own, and the third is [the official Google demo](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html). None are detecting any audio in my main Chrome browser. The error message that is associated with `recognition.onerror` is simply "no-speech".

When I use Chrome Canary everything is working fine.

I have several audio input devices connected to my Mac (including the built-in microphone) and have tried changing my microphone settings to each one. All of them work without a problem in Chrome Canary, but nothing is working in regular Chrome. I can also see that the input levels are nominal in the MacOS system preferences for each input device.

[image: audio input devices]

Chrome does ask to access the microphone, but after I accept no speech is detected. I can see that `onstart` and `onaudiostart` events are triggering, but after a few seconds of nothing the `onerror` and `onaudioend` events trigger.

I then tried clearing my browser cache/settings and restarting the browser with no luck. I have also tried a guest window and an incognito window (as well as disabling all extensions) and those did not work either. Last thing I tried was disabling all changed experimental flags, but no luck. I'm not sure how else to troubleshoot this problem...

**Is there another setting I am missing that may have been disabled or something somewhere (maybe even in MacOS)?**

Like I mentioned, I used to use this quite a bit in this same browser without any problems, but then after about a year of not using it somehow it stopped detecting audio.

Answer (score 1):

Of course I would find the answer immediately after posting it. There **is** a MacOS setting that got disabled: In System Preferences under "Security & Privacy", then in the "Privacy" tab I found "Microphone" in the list on the left and noticed that Google Chrome was unchecked. Once I checked that box and restarted Chrome, it worked perfectly.

[image: microphone access in macos]

Hope this helps anyone else that runs into this problem!